# android/java split problem

Tags: java, android, split

```
String time = starttime.getText().toString();

String[] separated = time.split(":");

test.setText("HH:" + separated[0].toString() + "MM:" + separated[1].toString());
```

If i type in 11:11 in my app, i get arrayoutofboundsexception. Ive tried trim() on the string as well. Did i miss something?

Comment: Tried ´String[] separated = TextUtils.split(time, ":");´ as well

Comment: Please show your input code.  There are definitely things being done here that are unnecessary, but the root of the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: And i tried escaping the : with \\. ("\\:")

Comment: The input comes from an EditText control

Answer (score 1):

No, *you* didn't miss something. I guess, *the input* misses a colon (`:`). Double check the format of `time` right before the split operation.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the chinese keyboard on the emulator? It looks like a colon, but might be something else?